# How to add classes to Wordpress navigation menu items based on custom advanced menu options

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, customization

I found this code which has allowed me to add custom fields to the advanced options in the Wordpress menu editor:

```
/*
 * Saves new field to postmeta for navigation
 */
add_action('wp_update_nav_menu_item', 'megamenu_nav_update',10, 3);
function megamenu_nav_update($menu_id, $menu_item_db_id, $args ) {
    if ( is_array($_REQUEST['menu-item-megamenu']) ) {
        $megamenu_value = $_REQUEST['menu-item-megamenu'][$menu_item_db_id];
        update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_megamenu', $megamenu_value );
    }
    if ( is_array($_REQUEST['menu-item-megamenu_col']) ) {
        $megamenu_col_value = $_REQUEST['menu-item-megamenu_col'][$menu_item_db_id];
        update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_megamenu_col', $megamenu_col_value );
    }
    if ( is_array($_REQUEST['menu-item-megamenu_alignment']) ) {
        $megamenu_alignment_value = $_REQUEST['menu-item-megamenu_alignment'][$menu_item_db_id];
        update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_megamenu_alignment', $megamenu_alignment_value );
    }
}

/*
 * Adds value of new field to $item object that will be passed to     Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit_Custom
 */
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item','megamenu_nav_item' );
function megamenu_nav_item($menu_item) {
    $menu_item->megamenu = get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_megamenu', true );
    $menu_item->megamenu_col = get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_megamenu_col', true );
    $menu_item->megamenu_alignment = get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_megamenu_alignment', true );
    return $menu_item;
}

add_filter( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', 'custom_nav_edit_walker',10,2 );
function custom_nav_edit_walker($walker,$menu_id) {
    return 'Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit_Custom';
}

/**
 * Copied from Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit class in core
 * 
 * Create HTML list of nav menu input items.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @uses Walker_Nav_Menu
 */

class Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit_Custom extends Walker_Nav_Menu  {
    /**
     * @see Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference.
     */
     
    
     
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) { 
    }
    
    /**
     * @see Walker_Nav_Menu::end_lvl()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference.
     */
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    }
    
    /**
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item Menu item data object.
     * @param int $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param object $args
     */
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        global $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth;
       
        $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth = $depth > $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth ? $depth : $_wp_nav_menu_max_depth;
    
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    
        ob_start();
        $item_id = esc_attr( $item->ID );
        $removed_args = array(
            'action',
            'customlink-tab',
            'edit-menu-item',
            'menu-item',
            'page-tab',
            '_wpnonce',
        );
    
        $original_title = '';
        if ( 'taxonomy' == $item->type ) {
            $original_title = get_term_field( 'name', $item->object_id, $item->object, 'raw' );
            if ( is_wp_error( $original_title ) )
                $original_title = false;
        } elseif ( 'post_type' == $item->type ) {
            $original_object = get_post( $item->object_id );
            $original_title = $original_object->post_title;
        }
    
        $classes = array(
            'menu-item menu-item-depth-' . $depth,
            'menu-item-' . esc_attr( $item->object ),
            'menu-item-edit-' . ( ( isset( $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) && $item_id == $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) ? 'active' : 'inactive'),
        );
    
        $title = $item->title;
    
        if ( ! empty( $item->_invalid ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'menu-item-invalid';
            /* translators: %s: title of menu item which is invalid */
            $title = sprintf( __( '%s (Invalid)','rdesign' ), $item->title );
        } elseif ( isset( $item->post_status ) && 'draft' == $item->post_status ) {
            $classes[] = 'pending';
            /* translators: %s: title of menu item in draft status */
            $title = sprintf( __('%s (Pending)','rdesign'), $item->title );
        }
    
        $title = empty( $item->label ) ? $title : $item->label;
    
        ?>
        <li id="menu-item-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>" class="<?php echo implode(' ', $classes ); ?>">
            <dl class="menu-item-bar">
                <dt class="menu-item-handle">
                    <span class="item-title"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></span>
                    <span class="item-controls">
                        <span class="item-type"><?php echo esc_html( $item->type_label ); ?></span>
                        <span class="item-order hide-if-js">
                            <a href="<?php
                                echo wp_nonce_url( esc_url( add_query_arg(
                                        array(
                                            'action' => 'move-up-menu-item',
                                            'menu-item' => $item_id,
                                        ),
                                        remove_query_arg($removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' )))
                                    ),
                                    'move-menu_item'
                                );
                            ?>" class="item-move-up"><abbr title="<?php esc_attr_e('Move up','rdesign'); ?>">&#8593;</abbr></a>
                            |
                            <a href="<?php
                                echo wp_nonce_url(
                                esc_url( add_query_arg(
                                        array(
                                            'action' => 'move-down-menu-item',
                                            'menu-item' => $item_id,
                                        ),
                                        remove_query_arg($removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) ) )
                                    ),
                                    'move-menu_item'
                                );
                            ?>" class="item-move-down"><abbr title="<?php esc_attr_e('Move down','rdesign'); ?>">&#8595;</abbr></a>
                        </span>
                        <a class="item-edit" id="edit-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e('Edit Menu Item','rdesign'); ?>" href="<?php
                            echo ( isset( $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) && $item_id == $_GET['edit-menu-item'] ) ? admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) : esc_url( add_query_arg( 'edit-menu-item', $item_id, remove_query_arg( $removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php#menu-item-settings-' . $item_id ) ) ) );
                        ?>"><?php _e( 'Edit Menu Item','rdesign' ); ?></a>
                    </span>
                </dt>
            </dl>
    
            <div class="menu-item-settings" id="menu-item-settings-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>">
                <?php if( 'custom' == $item->type ) : ?>
                    <p class="field-url description description-wide">
                        <label for="edit-menu-item-url-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>">
                            <?php _e( 'URL','rdesign' ); ?><br />
                            <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-url-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-url" name="menu-item-url[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->url ); ?>" />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <p class="description description-thin">
                    <label for="edit-menu-item-title-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>">
                        <?php _e( 'Navigation Label','rdesign' ); ?><br />
                        <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-title-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>" class="widefat edit-menu-item-title" name="menu-item-title[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->title ); ?>" />
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p class="description description-thin">
                    <label for="edit-menu-item-attr-title-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>">
                        <?php _e( 'Title Attribute','rdesign' ); ?><br />
                        <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-attr-title-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>" class="widefat edit-menu-item-attr-title" name="menu-item-attr-title[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->post_excerpt ); ?>" />
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p class="field-link-target description">
                    <label for="edit-menu-item-target-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="edit-menu-item-target-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>" value="_blank" name="menu-item-target[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]"<?php checked( $item->target, '_blank' ); ?> />
                        <?php _e( 'Open link in a new window/tab','rdesign' ); ?>
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p class="field-css-classes description description-thin">
                    <label for="edit-menu-item-classes-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>">
                        <?php _e( 'CSS Classes (optional)','rdesign' ); ?><br />
                        <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-classes-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-classes" name="menu-item-classes[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( implode(' ', $item->classes ) ); ?>" />
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p class="field-xfn description description-thin">
                    <label for="edit-menu-item-xfn-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>">
                        <?php _e( 'Link Relationship (XFN)','rdesign' ); ?><br />
                        <input type="text" id="edit-menu-item-xfn-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-xfn" name="menu-item-xfn[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->xfn ); ?>" />
                    </label>
                </p>
                <?php
                /* New fields insertion starts here */
                ?>      
                <p class="field-megamenu-status description description-wide">
                    <label for="edit-menu-item-megamenu-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="edit-menu-item-megamenu-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>" value="megamenu" name="menu-item-megamenu[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]"<?php checked( $item->megamenu, 'megamenu' ); ?> />
                    <?php _e( 'Enable megamenu','rdesign' );    ?>
                    </label>
                </p>

                <p class="field-megamenu-columns description description-wide">
                    <label for="edit-menu-item-megamenu_col-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>">
                        <?php _e( 'Megamenu columns (from 2 to 6)','rdesign' ); ?><br />
                        <?php $saved_megamenu_col = esc_attr( $item->megamenu_col ); ?>
                        <select id="edit-menu-item-megamenu_col-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-custom" name="menu-item-megamenu_col[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]">
                            <option value="2" <?php if($saved_megamenu_col == "2"){echo("selected");} ?>>2</option>
                            <option value="3" <?php if($saved_megamenu_col == "3"){echo("selected");} ?>>3</option>
                            <option value="4" <?php if($saved_megamenu_col == "4"){echo("selected");} ?>>4</option>
                            <option value="5" <?php if($saved_megamenu_col == "5"){echo("selected");} ?>>5</option>
                            <option value="6" <?php if($saved_megamenu_col == "6"){echo("selected");} ?>>6</option>
                        </select>
                </label>
                </p>

                <p class="field-megamenu-alignment description description-wide">
                    <label for="edit-menu-item-megamenu_alignment-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>">
                        <?php _e( 'Megamenu alignment','rdesign' ); ?><br />
                        <?php $saved_megamenu_alignment = esc_attr( $item->megamenu_alignment ); ?>
                        <select id="edit-menu-item-megamenu_alignment-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-custom" name="menu-item-megamenu_alignment[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]">
                            <option value="left" <?php if($saved_megamenu_alignment == "left"){echo("selected");} ?>>Left</option>
                            <option value="center" <?php if($saved_megamenu_alignment == "center"){echo("selected");} ?>>Center</option>
                            <option value="right" <?php if($saved_megamenu_alignment == "right"){echo("selected");} ?>>Right</option>
                            <option value="space-around" <?php if($saved_megamenu_alignment == "space-around"){echo("selected");} ?>>Space Around</option>
                            <option value="space-evenly" <?php if($saved_megamenu_alignment == "space-evenly"){echo("selected");} ?>>Space Evenly</option>
                            <option value="space-between" <?php if($saved_megamenu_alignment == "space-between"){echo("selected");} ?>>Space Between</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </p>
                <?php
                /* New fields insertion ends here */
                ?>
                <div class="menu-item-actions description-wide submitbox">
                    <?php if( 'custom' != $item->type && $original_title !== false ) : ?>
                        <p class="link-to-original">
                            <?php printf( __('Original: %s','rdesign'), '<a href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) . '">' . esc_html( $original_title ) . '</a>' ); ?>
                        </p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <a class="item-delete submitdelete deletion" id="delete-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>" href="<?php
                    echo wp_nonce_url(
                    esc_url( add_query_arg(
                            array(
                                'action' => 'delete-menu-item',
                                'menu-item' => $item_id,
                            ),
                            remove_query_arg($removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) ) )
                        ),
                        'delete-menu_item_' . $item_id
                    ); ?>"><?php _e('Remove','rdesign'); ?></a> <span class="meta-sep"> | </span> <a class="item-cancel submitcancel" id="cancel-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( array('edit-menu-item' => $item_id, 'cancel' => time()), remove_query_arg( $removed_args, admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) ) ) );
                        ?>#menu-item-settings-<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>"><?php _e('Cancel','rdesign'); ?></a>
                </div>
    
                <input class="menu-item-data-db-id" type="hidden" name="menu-item-db-id[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>" />
                <input class="menu-item-data-object-id" type="hidden" name="menu-item-object-id[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->object_id ); ?>" />
                <input class="menu-item-data-object" type="hidden" name="menu-item-object[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->object ); ?>" />
                <input class="menu-item-data-parent-id" type="hidden" name="menu-item-parent-id[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->menu_item_parent ); ?>" />
                <input class="menu-item-data-position" type="hidden" name="menu-item-position[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->menu_order ); ?>" />
                <input class="menu-item-data-type" type="hidden" name="menu-item-type[<?php echo esc_attr($item_id); ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item->type ); ?>" />
            </div><!-- .menu-item-settings-->
            <ul class="menu-item-transport"></ul>
        <?php
        
        $output .= ob_get_clean();

        }
}
```

This code has allowed me to add a checkbox field to enable Megamenu, a dropdown field to select 2 - 6 columns for the Megamenu and a dropdown field to select the megamenu item alignment.

What I need to know now, however, is having saved these options, how can I now add classes to the navigation menu items based on the saved values?  i.e., if Megamenu is enabled, I need the class "mega-menu" to be added to the menu item <li>.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have managed to get this working using the following code:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'megamenu_nav_classes' , 10 , 2);
function megamenu_nav_classes($classes, $item){
    $item_id = esc_attr( $item->ID );
    $mega_menu = $item->$megamenu['_menu_item_megamenu'][0];
    $mega_menu_col = $item->$megamenu['_menu_item_megamenu_col'][0];
    $mega_menu_alignment = $item->$megamenu['_menu_item_megamenu_alignment'][0];

     if($mega_menu == 'megamenu'){
        $classes[] = 'mega-menu';
        $classes[] = 'col-'.$mega_menu_col;
        $classes[] = $mega_menu_alignment;
     }

     return $classes;
}
```

This does work, but can anyone tell me if this is the best way of going about this?  Or is there a better, 'cleaner' method?